# Trying to use the ConnectionFactory class created by singleton in DatabaseServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, service-provider

So Tapestry has its default DatabaseServiceProvider.php with the below code inside.

```
$this->app->singleton('db.factory', function ($app) {
    return new ConnectionFactory($app);
});
```

I want to be able to use the db.factory facade created by this to make a new connection. But when I call

```
db.factory::make($config,$factory);
```

Of course this doesn't work, I get an error:

> Use of undefined constant db - assumed 'db'

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That singleton has to be accessed directly through the [service container](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/container). My favorite way to do that is the `app()` helper function:

```
app('db.factory')->make($config, $factory);
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas, are you able to explain to me why. Trying to learn Laravel is pretty overwhelming for me

Comment: *why* is a pretty broad question... `db.factory::` would work if this was a facade. Facades basically do nothing else than resolve a certain class from the container (like we do with `app('db.factory')`) and "transform" a static method call into a dynamic one. That's not possible with `db.factory` because it doesn't have a facade. Let me know if something is unclear :)

Comment: No that's perfect thanks, now I'm off to try and find out why one of my middlewares has stopped working